# OSx mono gtk hello world. An exception was thrown for Gtk.Container

Tags: c#, macos, mono, gtk

Trying out the hello world examples in Mono after a new install. Tried the GTK example as instructed at [http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/][1]:

```
mcs hello.cs -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0
mono hello.exe
```

and I get this:

```
> 2014-11-21 21:45:29.629 mono[45107:1731007] *** WARNING: Method
> userSpaceScaleFactor in class NSView is deprecated on 10.7 and later.
> It should not be used in new applications. Use convertRectToBacking:
> instead. 
> 
> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception
> was thrown by the type initializer for Gtk.Container --->
> System.DllNotFoundException: gtksharpglue-2   at (wrapper
> managed-to-native)
> Gtk.Container:gtksharp_gtk_container_get_focus_child_offset ()   at
> Gtk.Container..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    --- End
> of inner exception stack trace ---   at Gtk.Bin..ctor (IntPtr raw)
> [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at Gtk.Window..ctor (WindowType
> type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at Gtk.Window..ctor
> (System.String title) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
> Hello.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  [ERROR] FATAL
> UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception
> was thrown by the type initializer for Gtk.Container --->
> System.DllNotFoundException: gtksharpglue-2   at (wrapper
> managed-to-native)
> Gtk.Container:gtksharp_gtk_container_get_focus_child_offset ()   at
> Gtk.Container..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    --- End
> of inner exception stack trace ---   at Gtk.Bin..ctor (IntPtr raw)
> [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
>    at Gtk.Window..ctor (WindowType type) [0x00000] in <filename
> unknown>:0 
>       at Gtk.Window..ctor (System.String title) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>       at Hello.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Any idea what's causing it?

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan Pryor answered this very nicely in a [Xamarin forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3385/gtk-application-crashes-on-osx). These bits from his answer helped me out:

> You're not exporting $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH or $DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH so that it can be found.
>
> ...
>
> The problem is that libgtk-quartz-2.0.0.dylib can't be found, because it's installed to /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Libraries, not /usr/lib (or anything global).

Run the following in your shell first, and thereafter `mono hello.exe` should work:

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib:/lib:/usr/lib
```

Comment: Note that Jonathan suggested creating a script (see below).  My experience is that OS X does not play well with changes to environment involving DYLD variables.

Answer (score 0):

The first error message,

> "userSpaceScaleFactor in class NSView is deprecated on 10.7 and later"

can be ignored by users of GTK.  However, the GTK developer community will have to update their code before the referenced call is removed by Apple.

[Apple Dev Community Notices re userSpaceScaleFactor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/MacOSXLionAPIDiffs/AppKit.html)

A script to isolate the 2nd problem.  Don't forget to chmod +x it.

```
#!/bin/zsh
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib:/lib:/usr/lib

mono $1.exe
```